# BJT differential pair

Tags: transistors

I am struck . Currently working in sedra Smith , I stumbled across this question in BJT differential pairs . now I am confused as to how to determine which transistor will conduct and which will not . 
Can anyone help me please
[image]

Comment: There is a schematic editor in the post editor (little icon at the top). Also, homework questions are off-topic here without a good-faith attempt to solve.

Comment: Stop thinking in transistors conducting or not, they **both** conduct. However, one will have a slightly larger VBE making it conduct slightly more current.

Comment: Think of it as a 'see saw' - Both start at the same current, as you add input to one the current though it goes up and takes the other down so the total current stays the same.

Answer (score 2):

An approach you might take is to simply make an assumption either way and then test it out. If it succeeds, then look further. If it fails, drop the idea and try out another one. A lot of questions like this one can be quickly figured out that way. The problem asks a simple "this or that" question. So assume one and test it out. Doesn't matter which you choose. See how it pans out.

For example: The base of \$Q_1\$ is \$+500\:\textrm{mV}\$. If it is **ON** (and given the specified assumption about \$\vert V_{BE}\vert=700\:\textrm{mV}\$), then it must be the case that \$Q_1\$'s emitter is at \$V_{B_1}-V_{BE}=500\:\textrm{mV}-\left(-700\:\textrm{mV}\right)=1.2\:\textrm{V}\$, right? But if so, then that would place all that voltage across \$Q_2\$'s base-emitter junction and wouldn't that mean that if \$Q_1\$ is **ON** then \$Q_2\$ must be so much more-so **ON**? Keep in mind that for every \$60\:\textrm{mV}\$ that the magnitude of \$V_{BE}\$ increases, the collector current increases by a factor of \$10\times\$.

Since with this assumption \$\vert V_{{BE_2}}\vert=\vert V_{{BE_1}}\vert+500\:\textrm{mV}\$, that's more than \$ 10^8\times\$ the collector current in \$Q_2\$ than in \$Q_1\$. Or, put otherwise, \$Q_2\$ gets all the current and \$Q_1\$ gets practically none of it. And since the resistors are all the same value, the collector of \$Q_2\$ will be about as much lower than its base as its emitter is above its base. So \$V_E\approx +700\:\textrm{mV}\$ and \$V_{C_2}\approx -700\:\textrm{mV}\$. \$Q_1\$'s collector resistor has no current at all, so that collector voltage will be at the negative rail, or \$V_{C_1}\approx -5\:\textrm{V}\$.

---

Part of learning electronics is about applying logic. Part is about applying quantitative theory. Part still more is about imagination and not taking it personally when it fails, but instead just marching on with the next idea.

There is nothing to be ashamed of, in being wrong and having your errors handed to you on a silver platter for all to see. Happens to all of us. Just pick yourself up and move forward again. But there **is** something to be ashamed of in not exposing your thinking and imagining it is instead better to protect yourself from criticism by not letting others see into your mind much.

As an aside, you might take a look at this very much [related answer](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/273922/npn-differential-pair-emitter-voltage-variation/274057#274057) that I wrote, about something similar. It isn't at all a complete description even of something as simple as your circuit, but it will provide a taste of where you are headed.

Comment: A fat thanks dear . Truly speaking I was also resorting to this hit and trial method but then I don't know why but it didn't work but your answer helped me . Thank you for helping.

Comment: @yogibhandari Glad to hear it helped. I can't tell you why your "hit and trial" method wasn't working for you because *you didn't expose your thinking*. If you expose your detailed thinking to criticism, I think you will learn a lot faster and a lot better. You didn't here so I've no idea why your approach wasn't working for you. Perhaps another time.

Answer (score 0):

You could also go the other way around instead of start by inspecting Q1. Since it is a PNP differential pair, the BJT with the lowest voltage at its base will have "more possibilities" of conduct. Remember that Vbe < Vbeon (which is negative in PNP).

Assume that Q2 is conducting (ON) and therefore **Ve = 0.7 V**
This will lead a total consumption current of (5-0.7) / 1k = **4.3 mA**

Now what happens with Q1? We jut need to calculate its Vbe and see if the junction is forward biased and thus it conducts. **Vbe1** = 0.5 - 0.7 = **-0.2 V**

-0.2 is typically lower than VBEon. This means that Q1 is in OFF state.

Finally, the absence of current in Q1 branch means that **Vc1 = -5V**, and since all the current flows through the branch of Q2, **Vc2 = -0.7V**

I know you question was already answered but I just wanted you to see that there are many ways to analyse the same problem.

Have fun

Comment: You guys are so awesome. Thou my doubt was already cleared but still you made the concept crystal clear by elucidating the other scenario. Thank you guys for helping.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps another view of the diff. pair can help to improve understanding?

- Ground the base of Q2 and analyzw what you see: The most left transistor Q1 has an input signal at its input (base) - and the emitter is connected to another transistor (Q2).
- Hence, you can treat Q1 as an emitter follower loaded by another transistor in common-base configuration (because the base of Q2 is grounded). Hint: In spite of a collector resistor we can treat the emitter node as an emitter-follower output.
- As a result, we have a two-transistor combination: Emitter follower in series with a common-base stage.
- What happens when you increase the input signal for Q1? Answer: The emitter current of Q1 (and the voltage at the emitter) increases, thereby reducing VBE of Q2. As a result, the emitter current of Q2 reduces correspondingly.
- The same consideration is possible from the other side: Ground the base of Q1 and inject a signal into the base of Q2.