# Gain of single input differential amplifier

Tags: transistors, amplifier, bjt, differential, gain

When performing the small signal analysis of the circuit shown below, with \$ V_{1} = V_{in} \$ and \$ V_{2} = 0 \$, and output taken from \$ V_{02}\$, I consider the small signal model for half of the circuit, adjusting \$ R_E \$ into two parallel resistors of \$ 2R_E \$ . However, when asked to find the overall gain, by combining results for the differential and common mode gain, the textbook suggests in the small signal analysis \$ V_{in} \$ should be taken to be \$ \frac{1}{2}V_{in} \$. This gives the corresponding gain as \$ \frac{-h_{fe}R_{C1}}{2}\left( \frac{1}{h_{ie}}+\frac{1}{h_{ie} + (h_{fe}+1)2R_{E}}\right)      \$.

Is this to do with the idea that the common emitter point is shunted to an intermediate value between \$ V_{in} \$ and 0 ? Are the common mode and differential inputs being assumed to represent half of \$ V_{in} \$ ? I am a bit confused. Thanks.

[image]

Comment: You have two single-ended signals coming in and have only one differential output. Is this intended? Or is it okay to ground one of the inputs for this question? (I'm wondering how I might discuss gain in the context of two input signals of arbitrary waveform -- there would be two different differential variables for the two inputs.)

Comment: This diagram isn't the exact one from the question, in the question the \$ V_{in2} \$  and  \$ V_{01} \$ don't exist.

Comment: @jonk From what I see the OP has one single-ended input signal (Vin1) and the Q2 base is grounded. The the output signal is taken from Q1 collector (Vo1).  Therefor the gain becomes equal to \$\frac{V_{O1}}{V_{IN1}} = \frac{R_{C1}}{r_{e1} + R_E||r_{e2}}*\frac{\beta 1}{\beta 1 +1}\$

Comment: Because the voltage gain Vo2/Vin1 will be different. and the OP equation gives the correct answer for Vo1/Vin1 gain. It least this is how I see it.

Comment: Sounds way overly complex. Call tiny change at base of Q1, \$\text{d}V_i\$. If Q2 base is grounded and we start with Q1 base the same as Q2 base, then the shared emitter junction will experience \$\frac12 \text{d}V_i\$. This will have an opposing effect on Q2 collector current, multiplied by RC2 to get \$\text{d}V_o\$. If I know \$g_m\$, the whole thing seems really simple to me.

Comment: Why didn't you come up with about \$\frac{1}{2}\,g_m\, R_{\text{C}_2}\$?

Comment: If you want to know more details about the \$\frac12\$ part, you can look [here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/274057/38098). Down towards the bottom of my answer you'll see \$\frac12\$ finally appear as a result.

Comment: The most simple way to analyze this configuration is to realize that we have a two-stage amplifier consisting of a common collector and a common base stage. Classical analyze techniques result in (gm*Rc2)/2

Comment: @bebop Is there something still missing from your understanding? I wrote a very simple equation and gave a very easy to understand process about arriving at it. LvW later wrote and agrees with me (for entirely different thinking processes.) So you have two completely independent ways to arriving at the exact same quantitative result. Are you looking still for something different??

Comment: No, your explanations were very helpful, thanks